# Force closes on subtype polymorphic object instantiation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, polymorphism, subtyping

I have the following setup:

```
public abstract class Parent {
    // logic for class
    public virtual int Value {get;set;}
    public Parent(){}
}

public class Child1 : Parent {
    // child specific logic here
    public Child1 () : base() {
        base.Value = 4;
    }
}

public class Child2 : Parent {
    // child specific logic here
    public Child2 () : base() {
        base.Value = 6;
    }
}

public class RunMe {
    Parent p;

    public Parent instantiateObject(string s) {
        switch(s) {
            case "child1":
                return new Child1();
            break;
            default:
            case "child2":
                return new Child2();
            break;
        }
    }

    public RunMe() {
        p = instantiateObject("child1");
    }
}
```

when I run code similar to this, Unity force closes.  I know C# supports subtype polymorphism, so I'm not really sure why this isn't working.  It is nothing special or advanced; so I'm super confused.  Shameless admission, I'm in the java camp, and I do (un)consciously try to fit my java paradigm into the C# paradigm. Am I not using it correctly or am I not understanding how sub-typing works in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that using

```
base.Value = 4
```

On an accessor that is defined as `virtual` inside an `abstract` class causes problems.  As I'm not really comfortable with the more esoteric underpinnings of C# I don't really know or understand why this is the case.  But altering the code to look like this works:

```
public abstract class Parent {
    // logic for class
    public int Value {get;set;}
    public Parent(){}
}

public class Child1 : Parent {
    // child specific logic here
    public Child1 () : base() {
        base.Value = 4;
    }
}

public class Child2 : Parent {
    // child specific logic here
    public Child2 () : base() {
        base.Value = 6;
    }
}

public class RunMe {
    Parent p;

    public Parent instantiateObject(string s) {
        switch(s) {
            case "child1":
                return new Child1();
            break;
            default:
            case "child2":
                return new Child2();
            break;
        }
    }

    public RunMe() {
        p = instantiateObject("child1");
    }
}
```

Notice I removed the `virtual` keyword from my accessor in my abstract class `Parent`

Answer (score 0):

Your member name "RunMe" is the same as your class "RunMe." You would use "RunMe" as your class constructor:

```
public RunMe() {
```

As far as your sub-typing, I see nothing wrong with the way you have it implemented. It should work as you described.

Comment: Sure I understand that that `RunMe()` is the constructor for the class.  But my implementation that is identical to this force closes the Unity3d environment when I try to do this.

Comment: Your constructor RunMe has a return value of "void." I haven't seen this syntax before and your constructor is really returning an object reference, so it shouldn't be void. Are you receiving any other errors? Is your program compiling?

Comment: Haha, I accidently added the void.  Apparently I didn't proofread that well enough.  It's been changed.

Comment: I edited my code to be more inclusive of what I'm trying to do.  The problem apparently is with the `virtual` declaration in the `parent` class.  I don't fully understand why this is the case.  The MSDN documentation isn't very clear to me as to why this is the case.